# setDefaultOptions() must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::setDefaultOptions()

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am working on a project based on Symfony 2.7.

I have added the following function a custom form type:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(
      [
          'error_bubbling' => true
      ]
    );
}
```

... and when loading the form, I now get the following FatalErrorException:

> Compile Error: Declaration of
>   MyCompany\AppBundle\Form\ContactType::setDefaultOptions() must be
>   compatible with
>   Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::setDefaultOptions(Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface
>   $resolver)

Glancing at `FormTypeInterface::setDefaultOptions()`, it appears that I am complying with the method signature. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Typehint `OptionsResolverInterface` is not the same as `OptionsResolver`

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I tried Cid's answer, and it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either type `$resolver` correctly, it's expected to be `OptionsResolverInterface`, not `OptionsResolver`.

Or, better to replace `setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)` by `configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)` since it's deprecated in Symfony 2.7 [source](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-form-and-validator-updates#deprecated-setdefaultoptions-in-favor-of-configureoptions)

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(
        [
            'error_bubbling' => true
        ]
    );
}
```